# Why do people have different sense of humour?

Tags: humour

Why some people find dark humour funny but other people feel embarrassed when they hear such jokes? Some people laugh at cabarates but other feel bored watching them. What is the reason that people have different sense of humour?

Comment: I've noticed that intelligent people like dark humour. Has anyone else observed the same? What might be the reason for this?

Comment: I think that intelligent people are confronting their fears in that way. I've noticed that also. @devlero

Comment: lol, I have an IQ of 140 and I dislike "dark" humor.

Comment: You have no fears @what :)

Comment: maybe you want to add some sources you have look at